# SSL routines:ssl23_write:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177

Tags: azure, ssl, https, command

I have created Azure VM and installed my application on it.

Created JKS file and configured SSL in my application.

I have restricted my Azure VM to access from particular source IP.

When I try to access from that source IP, I am not able to access my application from browser. It says "Site not found" error.

```
openssl s_client -connect 10.6.0.10:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
139868717622936:error:140790E5:SSL routines:ssl23_write:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 305 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1510229915
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```